# Identify requests coming from PageWorker

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible, from within the "http-on-modify-request" event, to identify which requests are coming from a PageWorker object, as opposed to those coming from visible tabs/windows?

Note: Because of redirects and subresources, the URL here is NOT the same URL as the pageWorkers contentURL property.

```
require("sdk/system/events").on("http-on-modify-request", function(e) {

    var httpChannel = e.subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel), 
        url = httpChannel.URI.spec, 
        origUrl = httpChannel.originalURI.spec;

    ...         
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way to actually distinguish `page-worker` requests from "regular" ones.

Current, page workers are implemented like this:

- The SDK essentially creates an `<iframe>` in the `hiddenWindow` (technically, in `sdk/addon/window`, which creates a hidden window in the `hiddenWindow`). The `hiddenWindow` in mozilla applications is more or less an always-present top-level XUL or HTML window that is simply hidden.
- The worker page is loaded into that `iframe`.
- The page-worker will then operate on the DOM on that `iframe`.

It is possible to [identify requests originating from the hidden window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19101474/484441) and the document within the hidden window.

But identifying if the request or associated document belongs to a `page-worker`, let alone which `page-worker` instance, doesn't seem possible, judging from the code. The SDK itself could map the document associated with a request back to a `page-worker`, as it keeps some `WeakMap`s around to do so, but that is internal stuff you cannot access.

You only can say that a request is not coming from a page-worker when it is not coming from the `hiddenWindow`.

Also, keep in mind that there are tons of requests originating neither from a `tab` nor `page-worker`: Other (XUL) windows, add-ons, js modules and components, etc...

If it a `page-worker` created by your add-on that you're interested in: The `contentURL` property should reflect the final URI once the page is loaded.

Comment: This seems a quite common use-case, where you launch a PageWorker and then want to monitor what its doing with event listeners (e.g., for 'http-on-modify-request'). Perhaps this is worth submitting as an enhancement ticket?

Comment: The hack I'm currently using is to modify the source of page-worker.js and make the view property an accessible field of the Page object. After constructing a Page p, I can give it an attribute: `p.view.setAttribute("MY-TAG", "xxx");` which I can then check in the listener methods, by accessing the request's chromeEventHandler. This seems to do what I want, but its just a temporary hack...

Comment: Lastly, a question: what do you mean by "the final URI"? When listening to 'http-on-modify-request' or 'http-on-examine-response' events, the contentURL of the PageWorker is the FIRST request I see, followed by many others (redirects, sub-resources, etc). I'm not sure, actually, how to tell when the page has fully loaded...

Comment: `http-on-modify-request` is not an event listener FWIW. "final URI" as in the URI the page/frame gets to after it is done loading (after any redirects and so on). Also, I don't really get what you're intending to solve here... It sounds more and more to me that you might be trying to use the wrong tool to solve your problem...

Comment: Its pretty simple actually. I want to visit pages with the PageWorker, and then potentially cancel some of the subrequests that result (images, sound, redirects, etc.)